# Look word inside file in directory

Tags: bash, script, directory-listing

I am new at Bash. I have a directory `tags` with a lot of `.txt` files with similar names like this

```
[coral/home/tags]$ ls:
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt
```

Each `.txt` file contains information like this:

```
line1 b1
line2 b2
line3 b3
line4 b4
```

I want to look in every text file and find those with the word `b3`. If the file contains that word I want the script to write the entire line and the text file that contains such word.

This is my failed attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env                                                           
PATH=path/to/files
for x in $PATH:
do
  echo $x
done
```

Comment: you want the output to be `line3 b3 filename.txt`?

Comment: yes, the line with b3 and the name of those files that contains it

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind using grep:

in `tags` directory:
`grep -Hrn 'b3' .`

- `-H` prints filename (implied when multiple files being searched)
- `-r` searches recursively
- `-n` prints line number
- `.` wildcard

Potentially interesting option:
`grep -C 3 'b3' path/to/files` 
you can adjust the `-C`ontext number of lines returned before and after a match (here, it's `3`).

Comment: I tried the command line but nothing happens, and if a try a bash script using grep it returns: grep:command not found

Comment: What linux distribution are you using?  You many need to install grep (it is normally standard)

Comment: a have ubuntu 12.04, and i think grep is install since when typing echo grep it returns /bin/grep